# How to get all the matches matched the inner groups in RegEx .exec results

Tags: javascript, regex

here is my code:

```
var regEx = /^abcd(\d)+efg$/i;
var data = "abcd1234efg";
var match = regEx.exec(data);
```

the result is:

```
["abcd1234efg","4"]
```

But what I want is every single number: 1,2,3,4, not only 4

how do i get it ?

**add another example:**

```
var regEx = /^abcd(xy|z)+efg$/i;
var data = "abcdxyzefg"; 
var match = regEx.exec(data);
```

what i want is ["abcdxyzefg","xy,"z"]. especially "xy" and "z"

thx~~

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you want between the `abcd` and the `efg`. Is it "any number"? (digits only?) or is it "anything" (digits/a-z/special chars)? Or only a-z characters? Without the **exact** requirements it's hard to help.

Comment: I want all the matches matched the inner group ,such as  (xy|z) .  var data = "abcdxyzefg",we know 'xy' and 'z' both match, so i want them both.But Regex.exec can return just the last matches:"z"

Comment: what makes the Z so special? Why not "x" and "yz"? You need to be more precise..

Comment: Another example:``var regEx = /^abcd(dog\d)+efg$/i;
var data = "abcddog1dog2dog7efg"; 
var match = regEx.exec(data);`` I want ["dog1", "dog2","dog7"] not only "dog7"

Comment: Yet again, you are not explaing the general scenario

Comment: When you repeat a capture group, each capture is overwritten with the next. That's why you obtain the last digit. Javascript doesn't store previous captures.

Comment: Thx for your answer very much .So I can hardly use only Regex to reallize it ?

Answer (score 2):

you need to put the quantifier, the `+`, inside the group:

```
^abcd(\d+)efg$
```

https://regex101.com/r/P6qQUq/1

Comment: I want every single number. Another exmple:

`var regEx = /^abcd(xy|z)+efg$/i;
var data = "abcdxyzefg";
var match = data.match(regEx);`

what i want is ["abcdxyzefg","xy,"z"]. especially "xy" and "z"

Comment: in that case you could try something like `(xy|z|\d+)`

Comment: No. I want all the matches matched the inner groups : (xy|z) . Regex.exec can return just the last matches.